# Getting IzPack - Unpacker thread" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError while running JBOSS installer jar

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x

I am currently trying to install JBOSS EAP 7.4 in my RHEL. I am getting the below error while running the JBOSS installer.

Command to run Jboss installer:

```
java -jar jboss-eap-7.4.0-installer.jar -console
```

Error:

```
Exception in thread "IzPack - Unpacker thread" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.izforge.izpack.event.SummaryLoggerInstallerListener.afterPacks(SummaryLoggerInstallerListener.java:92)
    at com.izforge.izpack.installer.UnpackerBase.informListeners(UnpackerBase.java:457)
    at com.izforge.izpack.installer.Unpacker.run(Unpacker.java:497)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.izforge.izpack.util.SummaryProcessor.<clinit>(SummaryProcessor.java:66)
    ... 4 more
```